# OpenCV - Getting All Blob Pixels

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, blob, pixel

I have this image:

[image]

I've been using the [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) feature [`SimpleBlobDetector`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d7a/classcv_1_1SimpleBlobDetector.html) to identify the blobs of white pixels on the black background.  Code is below.

```
blobDetectorParameters = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
blobDetectorParameters.filterByArea = True
blobDetectorParameters.minArea = 1
blobDetectorParameters.maxArea = 100
blobDetectorParameters.minDistBetweenBlobs = 1
blobDetectorParameters.filterByCircularity = False
blobDetectorParameters.filterByColor = False
blobDetectorParameters.filterByConvexity = False
blobDetectorParameters.filterByInertia = False

detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(blobDetectorParameters)
keypoints = detector.detect(image)
imageWithKeypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(image, keypoints, numpy.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", imageWithKeypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Which correctly identifies the blobs as shown in the image below:

[image]

**The question**: I want to be able to have a list of all the blob pixels in order to paint them out.  I can't seem to find a way, using the `SimpleBlobDetector`, to return the pixels of all blobs. I can get the keypoints (returned via `detect`), but I believe those correspond to the blob centers.

I should also add that I only want to paint blobs of a certain size out, which is why a blanket method of grabbing all the white pixels is not ideal.

Is there any function related to the `SimpleBlobDetector` (or elsewhere within OpenCV) to return *all* pixels related to *all* blobs?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You can use moments to compute the centroids and then draw white filled circles to cover them up. See https://www.learnopencv.com/find-center-of-blob-centroid-using-opencv-cpp-python/ for moments to centroids computation

Comment: @fmw42 I appreciate that suggestion but I need to be more precise in my painting since I don’t want to paint out all of the blobs, only ones of a certain size.  I need this method to be able to identify and eliminate blobs that are very close together but I don’t want to accidentally obscure any that should not be painted out.

Comment: Use nathancy's solution below.

Comment: If you can use skimage, it has a nice regionprops function that will return blob properties in your binary image, including areas, perimeters, centroids, etc. and importantly for your case, coordinates of each blob. Makes filtering a breeze!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) + [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) on the binary image to obtain the coordinates of all points. For this example I colored each point green onto a new mask. Here's the result

[image]

Here's the `(x,y)` coordinates of each pixel

```
[[ 28  32]
 [ 28  33]
 [ 29  33]
 [ 31  25]
 [ 31  26]
 [ 37  43]
 [ 37  44]
 [ 37  45]
 [ 38  43]
 [ 38  44]
 [ 38  45]
 [ 85  96]
 [118 116]
 [118 118]
 [119 116]
 [119 117]
 [120 116]
 [121  87]
 [121 115]
 [122  87]
 [122 115]
 [123  87]
 [123  97]
 [123 115]
 [124  87]
 [124  97]
 [124 115]
 [125  93]
 [125  95]
 [125  96]
 [125 114]
 [125 115]
 [126  94]
 [126  95]
 [126  96]
 [126 113]
 [126 114]
 [127  90]
 [127  94]
 [127  95]
 [127  96]
 [127 112]
 [127 113]
 [128  90]
 [128  91]
 [128  95]
 [128 102]
 [128 103]
 [128 104]
 [128 111]
 [128 112]
 [129 101]
 [129 102]
 [129 103]
 [129 104]
 [130  84]
 [130  85]
 [130 101]
 [130 102]]
```

Code

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0))
for coord in coords:
    mask[coord[0], coord[1]] = (36,255,12)

print(coords)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Update:** You can use contour area filtering to achieve your desired result. Specifically, we can use `cv2.findContours()` to grab the contours of all the blobs then filter using contour area with `cv2.contourArea()`. If the contour passes some minimum threshold area, then we draw it otherwise we ignore the contour. We can draw the blob with `cv2.drawContours()`, by passing in `-1` for the last parameter, we fill in the contour, otherwise any positive value will draw the outline of the blob. Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
threshold_area = 0.5
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > threshold_area:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (36,255,12), -1)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response, but - and I updated the OP to reflect this - I'm not looking to paint _all_ of the blobs out, only blobs of a certain size.  That's why I was hoping there would be a way to get the blob pixels from SimpleBlobDetector rather than grabbing all the white pixels.

Comment: @Antillies oh I see, check the update. You can use `cv2.findContours()` + `cv2.contourArea()` to filter the blobs based on some threshold area. If the blob passes this filter then we can paint the blob with `cv2.drawContours()`

Comment: That did it.  The only change I made to your code was to modify `threshold_area` to `min_threshold_area` and add a `max_threshold_area` comparator, altering the if statement to read `if area > min_threshold_area and area < max_threshold_area`.  Thank you for all of your help and insight.

As a parting final question, can I ask about this line: `cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]`.  What's the reasoning to grab the return 'image' if the counters equal two rather than the contours themselves?

Answer (score 1):

I think for your use case, you might benefit more from [findContours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html). You'll even see that the SimpleBlobDetector uses this function. It is mentioned in step 2 of the link you provided, but know that the contour only lists the outer pixels. If all you are doing is simply drawing each blob, then when using drawContours, you just need to set the thickness parameter to -1.

If you need to know each pixel value, then I would say the solution is to draw each contour and then record the pixel values into your own list. It's not totally clear what you're trying to use this for so it's hard to give you a straight answer, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a tad late by I encountered the same problem. I wanted to filter out smaller blobs. So I ended up writing this:

```
def filter_blobs(bin_img, min_size):
    label_ix = 1
    labels = np.zeros(shape=bin_img.shape)
    for j, row in enumerate(bin_img):
        for i, pix in enumerate(row):
            if pix > 0:
                above = labels[j-1][i] if j > 0 else None
                left = labels[j][i-1] if i > 0 else None
                if above and above > 0:
                    labels[j][i] = above
                    if left and left > 0:
                        labels[labels==left] = above
                elif left and left > 0:
                    labels[j][i] = left
                else:
                    labels[j][i] = label_ix
                    label_ix += 1
    for label in range(1, label_ix+1):
        filt = labels == label
        size = np.sum(filt)
        if size < min_size:
            bin_img[filt] = 0
    return label_ix, labels/np.max(labels)*255, bin_img

bin_img = np.round(np.random.rand(50,50))*255
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9.5,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1)
ax.imshow(bin_img, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
num_blobs, blob_img, filtered_img = filter_blobs(bin_img, 20)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2)
ax.imshow(blob_img, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
ax.set_title('# blobs: {}'.format(num_blobs))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,3,3)
ax.imshow(filtered_img, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Here's an example of the output:

[image]

Oddly satisfying to play with. If anyone can make this more efficient please comment!